# how to force delete topic from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

we do the following steps in order to delete the topic - **hgpo.llo.prmt.processed**

but even after 12 hours topics folders still not deleted from **/var/kafka/kafka-logs**

note - we set - delete.topic.enable=true

```
  hkafka01 kafka-logs]# /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper master01:2181 --alter --topic hgpo.llo.prmt.processed--config retention.ms=1000

  WARNING: Altering topic configuration from this script has been deprecated and may be removed in future releases. Going forward, please use kafka-configs.sh for this functionality Updated config for topic "hgpo.llo.prmt.processedd"

  kafka01 kafka-logs]# /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper master01:2181 --delete --topic hgpo.llo.prmt.processed 

  Topic hgpo.llo.prmt.processed is already marked for deletion.
```

how to force the topic deletion ?

on kafka machine ( production machine ) , we see that: ( no free space )

```
 /dev/sdb    15500450528 15500434144         0 100% /var/kafka
```

and under /var/kafka/kafka-logs , we still see all topic folders (huge size) as example: ( down )

so is it possible just to remove these folders as example - by

```
rm -rf hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-28 ?
```

under /var/kafka/kafka-logs we have many topic folders as :

```
 117G hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-28 
 117G hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-29
 117G hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-3
 117G hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-30
 117G hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-31
 117G hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-32
```

.
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deletion the way you've been trying should work but I'm guessing Kafka is not working well with a full disk.

As your disk is full, I'm assuming Kafka is not usable and a short downtime is acceptable. To delete the topic manually:

- Shutdown Kafka
- On all Kafka brokers that have replicas for `hgpo.llo.prmt.processed`, go to their data directory and delete the folders starting with `hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-`.
- Connect to Zookeeper with the `zookeeper-shell` tool
- Run: `rmr /brokers/topics/hgpo.llo.prmt.processed`
- Restart Kafka

To prevent this from happening again, I suggest you take a look at the retention policies Kafka offers to control disk usage

Comment: so i understand from your answer that I can use rm -rf to delete all toipics folders as hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-28  , hgpo.llo.prmt.processed-29 and so on  , can you confirm this ?

Comment: Just more two questions please , we have 3 zookeeper servers , si I guess it enough to do  rmr /brokers/topics/hgpo.llo.prmt.processed only of one of them , am I correct ?

Comment: do we need also to delete corresponding consumer offset from ZooKeeper under - /consumers/<consumer-of-topic>/offsets/<topic-name> ?

Comment: Yes you only need to run the `rmr` command on 1 of the zookeeper server.
If you are still running the old and deprecated Kafka consumer (0.8) yes you can delete the stored offsets, otherwise with the current clients the offsets are stored in Kafka and will be automatically deleted based on your `offsets.retention.minutes` value (default in Kafka 1.0.0 is 7 days)

Comment: thank you for your great answer , how to verify the Kafka consumer version  ?    ( on my kafka machine I see offsets.retention.minutes=86400000 can we set this values to be 1 day instead the current ? )

Answer (score 2):

A Kafka topic marked for deletion can be deleted by directly logging into the ZooKeeper shell and removing the topic metadata from the cluster. We also recommend removing the log segments from each broker that are associated with the topic.

1. zookeeper-shell
2. rmr /config/topics/
3. rmr /brokers/topics/
4. rmr /admin/delete_topics/
5. For each broker:

   - Shut down the broker
   - rm -R ${log.dirs}/-*
   - Start up the broker

Note: Step 5 should be done with care to ensure you are only removing the log directories for the topic you are intending to delete